# Cornice to bevel

Tags: modifiers, add-on

Is there any addon to make a cornice. With different profile shapes. Or where can i get the different shapes of profile of cornice[image]

Comment: i mean ready made different types of shapes

Comment: I made a pack of these https://blendermarket.com/products/crown-molding-pack/

Comment: @JeffLange yes but where to find different types of shapes or design. Addon provides many different shapes and settings for example in extra object we add torus and it has many settings we can twist and make different shapes. Thanks for replying

Answer (score 4):

A flexible way to do this is by creating a curve with the basic outline you want:

[image]

Then add a second curve and have it use the first curve as bevel object with end caps enabled
:

[image]

Comment: yes but where to find different types of shapes or design. Addon provides many different shapes and settings for example in extra object we add torus and it has many settings we can twist and make different shapes. Thanks for replying